Why should ntfsclone image a partition at a rate of 1Mb/s?
Edit: well, it's over and done w/. I executed ntfsclone -so ~/same_drive.img /dev/sda4 where ~ is on /dev/sda2 and it took just under an hour. I can't understand why that didn't work before, but I'm not terribly interested in getting that answered at this point.
Original problem
I have a 7200rpm hdd (ST31000524AS) that has a ~100Gb NTFS partition which is around 85% full. Now I'm using ntfsclone (ntfsclone -so here.img /dev/sda4) to back it up to a large ext4 file system on a 1Tb hdd through a USB 3.0 interface. Now as I understand it, even USB 2.0 should be able to transfer much faster than 1Mb/s. So where could the slow down be? My DSL is faster than that.
lsusb -tv says:
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
        ID 152d:0578 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JMS578 SATA 6Gb/s

That looks pretty good to me. iotop doesn't indicate that anything except ntfsclone is using doing much i/o (which has disk reads and writes running from 0 to around 500K/s). After after 24hrs of transferring, it's only 50% done.
When coming up with ideas, please first consider solutions that won't interfere with the progress so far. I'd hate to have to start all over again.
This is being done on Ubuntu 22.04.4.

@JoepvanSteen I should hope so; it came with the enclosure. The drive is a Barracuda, ST1000LM048.

One reason could be bad or weak sectors.  If the drive has to re-read the sectors multiple times it will slow it down significantly, but this may not be the only factor.  You could do a smartctl and see if the error counts increasing.

@cybernard In my experience, failing drive performances fall off a cliff. Like, they spend very little time between 100% functionality and 0. Well I read somewhere that the only figure that really mattered here is Raw_Read_Error_Rate. So if value/worst/thresh are 083/066/006, what does that tell you?

What is the ECC correction rate?

@cybernard I don't think there is one. Might it be called something else?
